# Jekyll gem breaks when adding Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I have my website in jekyll. All worked fine untill I did something (not sure what) and the installation broke.

I have tried this on Ubuntu WSL and on Windows native ruby, the issue is the same. I can install gems fine. And jekyll runs correctly, but if I add gemfile and run jekyll again (`bundle exec jekyll -v` or even `jekyll -v` in that folder) in other directories jekyll runs fine, and if I remove Gemfile, jekyll runs as well.

The error is:

```
bundle exec jekyll -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
        23: from C:/tools/ruby26/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        22: from C:/tools/ruby26/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        21: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        20: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:53:in `require_from_bundler'
        19: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
        18: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
        17: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
        16: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'         15: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
        14: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        13: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
        12: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll-thumb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'        11: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll-thumb.rb:1:in `require'
        10: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll/thumb.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'         9: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll/thumb.rb:2:in `require'
         8: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll/thumb/tag.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-thumb-0.2.1/lib/jekyll/thumb/tag.rb:1:in `require'              6: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.16/lib/ruby-vips.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'              5: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.16/lib/ruby-vips.rb:1:in `require'
         4: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.16/lib/vips.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
         3: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ruby-vips-2.0.16/lib/vips.rb:45:in `<module:GLib>'
         2: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:99:in `ffi_lib'              1: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.3-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:99:in `map'
block in ffi_lib: Could not  (LoadError) 'libglib-2.0-0.dll': Not found
```

(is exactly the same on WSL except it's `libglib-2.0-0.so`)

My gemfile is this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-paginate-v2"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap"
  gem "jekyll-org"
  gem "jekyll-thumb"
  gem "flickraw"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

From what I've concluded the version of jekyll (or it's dependency) when supplying Gemfile is corrupt in some way, yet when I look at bundler's output it's the global gem installed manually. I have even tried placing libglib-2.0-0.dll into system32 directory.

Versions of packages:

```
ruby: 2.6.5 [x64-mingw32]
bundler: 2.1.2
gem: 3.0.3
jekyll: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the version of Jekyll you are running in the Gemfile. The one you have locally is working so this is what you can try.
Run `jekyll -v` **outside** of the directory where jekyll fails. Replace the version in your Gemfile with the one that is outputted and `bundle install`.

I think that should work.

Edit: You need to put the jekyll gem inside your Gemfile like this:
`gem "jekyll"`

Otherwise you should try installing the [libglib package it says is missing](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libglib2.0-0).

Comment: as you can see, I am running the same version of jekyll. I tried putting the version inside Gemfile. `jekyll -v` outputs 4.0.0 but inside the folder it fails nonetheless

Comment: Can you check out the edits I made to the answer. I think they might be the problem.

Comment: no, the issue still persist. As for the library I have it installed. On my windows as well as on ubuntu

Comment: Ruby ffi needs to be able to find the shared library. Under WSL it needs to be in one of the lib areas managed by ldconfig, or you need to add the folder it's in to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. On Windows, you need to add the folder with all the libvips DLLs to `RUBY_DLL_PATH`.